# Amazon Connect Chat Queue Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I'm using an existing contact flow to accept phone calls and then move them to a queue via a Customer Queue Flow. This Customer Queue flow then uses a Loop prompt to check every 30 seconds how long the customer has been waiting in the queue. If they've been waiting longer than 5 minutes it ends the call.

I'm struggling to get the same flow working with web chat. If a person has been waiting to speak to an agent in a queue for X minutes then play a message and end the chat.

Loop Prompts are not compatible with web chat and I can't get wait blocks and loop prompts to simulate the same flow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After speaking with AWS Support...

"The loop prompt block is not yet available for chat queue as you've mentioned. It is expected behavior with this set up as when this block is triggered during a chat conversation the contact is routed down the Error Branch."

"However the service team has suggested a possible workaround, Wait Block followed by a Loop Block can be used.

The "Wait" block mainly checks to see if a customer is away from chat and hence not natively used for this functionality. You can make use of the "Wait" block to loop back and display a prompt. The block was set to 30 seconds and the message of your choice (In this case “Agent unavailable”) repeated itself after 30 seconds. There are however a few cons to using this block for this functionality relating to an “impatient” customer waiting to go on a chat and might randomly type within the chat prompt. This would reset the 30 second counter. Therefore, this work-around is not 100% full-proof but a viable option if needed."